# get groups that contain all needed values

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo',
                          'foo', 'foo'],
                    'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                  'C' : [2.0, 5., 8., 1., 2., 9.]})
>>> df
     A  B    C
0  bar  1  2.0
1  bar  2  5.0
2  bar  3  8.0
3  foo  4  1.0
4  foo  5  2.0
5  foo  6  9.0
```

How can I get the groups with both `neededVals = [1.0,2.0]` in C if I `groupby('A')`:

```
3  foo  4  1.0
4  foo  5  2.0
5  foo  6  9.0
```

And just those values as well:

```
3  foo  4  1.0
4  foo  5  2.0
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What is the example that you are giving. Why is there a row with 9.0?

Comment: @BramVanroy - because group `foo` I think.

Comment: question edited to show groupby('A')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need compare `set`s with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
neededVals = [1.0,2.0] 
df = df[df.groupby('A')['C'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set(neededVals))]
print (df)
     A  B    C
3  foo  4  1.0
4  foo  5  2.0
5  foo  6  9.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('A')['C'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set(neededVals)))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: C, dtype: bool
```

And for second first filter out unnecessary rows by `isin` and then compare equality:

```
df = df[df['C'].isin(neededVals)]
df = df[df.groupby('A')['C'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(neededVals))]
print (df)
     A  B    C
3  foo  4  1.0
4  foo  5  2.0
```

Comment: Under version 0.18.1 I am getting `KeyError: '[0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.] not in index'`. For some reason it returns 0./1. rather than `False/True`

Comment: Hmm, interesting, then cast to `boolean` like `df = df[df.groupby('A')['C'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set(neededVals)).astype(bool)]`